# Intellij idea doesn't run unit tests

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, junit

I'm working on a spring boot project and until recently it was fine but now i can't run unit tests. It gives the error:

`'int org.jvnet.winp.Native.setPriority(int, int)'`

I've searched but found nothing, what might couse the error?
(btw it runs the project itself just not the unit tests)

Edit: i just realized it works if i open the app by idea.bat file but not when i open with the exe file.

Comment: Does it work if you run project from the command line outside of IntelliJ? Please provide the entire error stacktrace.

Comment: I didn't try running on commend line but it works on another computer, and there is no stacktrace because it fails on build stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened a ticked at jetbrains, and turns out it was cousing by a third party security tool.